# Why Boiler plate is not showing in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I installed vs code but I cannot see boiler plate all the other Emmet recommendations are working but only boiler plate is not showing. I tried to find solutions on net but no luck.

Any suggestions how to fix it ? [Boiler plate recommendation is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPuQY.jpg)

Comment: It is a bug in the latest version of vscode, see the duplicate link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to **settings** or press `Ctrl+,` ->**Extension** -> **Emmet** and add item
with **include language** you have `key` and `value` set for example

```
html

vue
```

...etc

If you want to use the Tab key for expanding the Emmet abbreviations, add the following setting:

```
"emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true
```

this link is useful [emmet for vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet)

hopefully that is help you